# Replacing smart objects in bulk with Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

Just facing this issue: I have a mockup in Photoshop with two smart-objects: Rectangle 14.psb and Place your logo.psb 
I have 100+ images in png that should be applied to create mockups.
For this reason, I would like your help to create a script that:

Let me select the png file that I would like to use

Open the smart objects (Rectangle 14.psb and Place your logo.psb)

Re-Link the same png to the layers "place your logo" of both the smart objects.

Finally, the script should save the file as png with the same file name of the selected png file adding just _new after its name.

So far I have tried this code without any luck:

```
#target photoshop
if (app.documents.length > 0) {
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var theName = myDocument.name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
var thePath = myDocument.path;
var theLayer = myDocument.activeLayer;
// PSD Options;
psdOpts = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();
psdOpts.embedColorProfile = true;
psdOpts.alphaChannels = true;
psdOpts.layers = true;
psdOpts.spotColors = true;
// Check if layer is SmartObject;
if (theLayer.kind != "LayerKind.SMARTOBJECT") {
    alert("selected layer is not a smart object")
} else {
    // Select Files;
    if ($.os.search(/windows/i) != -1) {
        var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", 
"*.psd;*.tif;*.jpg;*.png", true)
    } else {
        var theFiles = File.openDialog("please select files", getFiles, 
true)
    };
    if (theFiles) {
        for (var m = 0; m < theFiles.length; m++) {
            // Replace SmartObject
            theLayer = replaceContents(theFiles[m], theLayer);
            var theNewName = theFiles[m].name.match(/(.*)\.[^\.]+$/)[1];
            // Save JPG
            myDocument.saveAs((new File(thePath + "/" + theName + "_" + 
theNewName + ".psd")), psdOpts, true);
        }
    }
}
};
// Get PSDs, TIFs and JPGs from files
function getFiles(theFile) {
if (theFile.name.match(/\.(psd|png|jpg)$/i) != null || 
theFile.constructor.name == "Folder") {
    return true
};
};
// Replace SmartObject Contents
function replaceContents(newFile, theSO) {
app.activeDocument.activeLayer = theSO;
// =======================================================
var idplacedLayerReplaceContents = 
stringIDToTypeID("placedLayerReplaceContents");
var desc3 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
desc3.putPath(idnull, new File(newFile));
var idPgNm = charIDToTypeID("PgNm");
desc3.putInteger(idPgNm, 1);
executeAction(idplacedLayerReplaceContents, desc3, DialogModes.NO);
return app.activeDocument.activeLayer
};
```

The above code substitute the smart object but I would like just to re-link the layer withing the smartobject to a new image and save the file. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "just to re-link the layer"? you want you SO to become a linked SO to that png file? I think it'd be useful to have a screenshot of current result VS the expected result

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [Scriptlistener](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html)? You can use it to get all the functions you need and then modify the output to run within your loop of 100 pngs, it should be straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem. There are a few main ways to automate mockup image creation inside of Photoshop.

1. You can use a simple Photoshop plugin which automates this process, such as [Batch Replace Smart Objects](https://exchange.adobe.com/apps/cc/8e3097ba/batch-replace-smart-objects). This basically takes all images from your source folder, replaces the Smart Object contents with each one, then exports each updated image to your output folder. If you're not experienced with writing Photoshop scripts / .jsx code, this is the easiest option to achieve this goal. It sounds like you're trying to do something a bit more complicated, however, so option 2/3 might be best in your specific case.
2. Use Photoshop scripting. Like Sergey recommended, use a "Script Listener" tool, such as [this one](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html) described by Adobe. This can allow you to run the desired operations (for example, replace a Smart Object with a specified image), then it'll log the Photoshop commands that get executed. You can then convert these Photoshop-friendly commands into the actual lines of .jsx code that's needed to perform your specified operations. *It's a little unclear from your original post what, exactly, you're trying to do -- vs. what the script already does -- so your best bet might be just, manually perform the actions yourself using a Scripting Listener, then use the outputted code that gets logged to just write the script that way.*
3. Another way to learn how to do this is to consult an Adobe Scripting reference guide. [This one on Github](https://github.com/rjduran/adobe-scripting) is a helpful resource to get you started. This will help you to understand how to actually write these Photoshop scripts to perform what's needed (instead of trying to just copy + paste stuff from the Script Listener and hope it happens to work.)